# Php artisan not working because i deleted the table in phpMyadmin , how to undo this?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I deleted a table directly in my phpMyAdmin and how when i run the command `php artsan migrate:rollback` , i get the following error:

Failed to open:stream: No such file or directory.

I already deleted the migration file from the migrations folder , so why am i getting this error ??

I was just going through the laravel migrations documentation **[HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations)**, and i saw the below command:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=5
```

So i tried the below in my command line:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
```

To rollback my last migration , but it does't seem to work. Thats the reason i deleted the table directly in the phpMyAdmin.

Below is the error i get now , when i run the `php artsan migrate:rollback`:

[image]

Comment: simply create the table with just an ID would do the trick. ;) All the rollback does is dropping the table and creating it, if needed. Might want to create the migration (an empty one) by just creating the file and inserting the default actions. Simply leave out the creation things since you just need it for deletion (php artisan make:migration <name>, then rename the file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following commands, it will be fine.

To clear cache

`php artisan cache:clear`

To composer autoload

`composer dump-autoload`

*Now restart your Laravel server and it will be fine.*

It will be working by now. However, it is never recommended to delete a table and a migration file directly. If that's the case, Laravel wouldn't have used migration at all. Please take care next time.

Answer (score 3):

Since you removed the file before rolling back, I would suggest to delete the entry manually from your `migrations` table.

Search for the full name and delete just the 1 entry.

```
DELETE FROM `migrations` where `name` = '[2017_01_09_xxx]';
```

---

However, if your migration was already committed and pushed to remote and other people are working on the same codebase, I would suggest restoring the table on your local env and also restore the migration file with that name and remove the table by adding a new migration.

This flow will make sure that when other people work with your changes or that when you deploy and run migrations, you are able to do so without issues.